# Formatting Phone Number Input In Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, format, phone-number

I have seen many solutions to formatting a phone number input field in Angularjs, but I cannot find anything on Angular 7. What I essentially want is for the user to type the following in the textfield:

> 123456789

and for the textfield to format the input as:

> (123) 456-789

how can I go about doing this? I have found the following regex to validate it:

```
^(\([0-9]{3}\) |[0-9]{3}-)[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{4}$
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can handle this with a Phone Mask Directive as follows,

```
export class PhoneMaskDirective {

  constructor(public ngControl: NgControl) { }

  @HostListener('ngModelChange', ['$event'])
  onModelChange(event) {
    this.onInputChange(event, false);
  }

  @HostListener('keydown.backspace', ['$event'])
  keydownBackspace(event) {
    this.onInputChange(event.target.value, true);
  }


  onInputChange(event, backspace) {
    let newVal = event.replace(/\D/g, '');
    if (backspace && newVal.length <= 6) {
      newVal = newVal.substring(0, newVal.length - 1);
    }
    if (newVal.length === 0) {
      newVal = '';
    } else if (newVal.length <= 3) {
      newVal = newVal.replace(/^(\d{0,3})/, '($1)');
    } else if (newVal.length <= 6) {
      newVal = newVal.replace(/^(\d{0,3})(\d{0,3})/, '($1) $2');
    } else if (newVal.length <= 10) {
      newVal = newVal.replace(/^(\d{0,3})(\d{0,3})(\d{0,4})/, '($1) $2-$3');
    } else {
      newVal = newVal.substring(0, 10);
      newVal = newVal.replace(/^(\d{0,3})(\d{0,3})(\d{0,4})/, '($1) $2-$3');
    }
    this.ngControl.valueAccessor.writeValue(newVal);
  }
}
```

[STACKBLITZ DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular6-phone-mask-qhcbnm)

Comment: I have one issue with this. On chrome, when you let it auto fill out the field, and immediately get the value, it is not formatted, although it looks like it is formatting. However, if you change the value, than it will work  Any thoughts?

Comment: is there any way so that selection for cursor do not shift at last place while removing any digit from input value ?

Answer (score 15):

You can easily install [ngx-mask](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-mask) package and then specify your ideal mask like this:

```
mask="(000) 000-000"

< input type="text" mask="(000) 000-000" />
```